# Firefox OS TCPSocket API : SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length

Tags: javascript, ssl, firefox-os

Is it possible to turn off SSL cert verification in Firefox OS? I have Geeksphone dev preview and try to make IMAP client via TCPSocket API, but server cert is somehow invalid. I got this error:

```
SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
(Error Code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)
```

My TCPSocket initializacion is as follows

```
var TCPSocket = navigator.mozTCPSocket.open(
        "mbp.telekom.de",
        993,
        {useSSL:'starttls'}
    );
```

When I try to connect to GMail or another account, everything works OK.

Is this really server cert error or is it something else?

Thanks

Comment: @JanKundrát, not sure whether this fits within the [tag:imap] tag, but this is actually related to IMAP: the two distinct ways it has to use SSL/TLS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning off the certificate verification is generally a bad idea and unlikely to help. The error says `ssl_error_rx_record_too_long`, and record that is too long is just too long, whether you choose to accept any certificate or not. This type of error tends to be caused by a record that is "too long for SSL/TLS", that is, some message that isn't valid SSL/TLS at all.

There are a few other problems here.

- According to the documentation, [`TCPSocket`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TCPSocket) takes a boolean for its `useSSL` parameter, not a string. It would seem fair to assume that somewhere in the code, there's an `if (useSSL) {...}`, so `'starttls'` in your configuration counts as `true`.
- Port 993 tends to be usable for IMAP over SSL (after an initial connection via SSL), not IMAP+STARTTLS on port 143 (where the same socket is upgraded to SSL/TLS after an initial plain-text connection).
- The server at `mbp.telekom.de` doesn't accept SSL/TLS initial connections (like most IMAP servers would on that port), but accepts plain text IMAP connections upgradable to SSL/TLS via STARTTLS (which it should do on port 143 instead). This is likely to be a problem with the server configuration. This also explain why your connection works with `imap.gmail.com` (since it does support normal SSL/TLS connection that don't use STARTTLS on port 993, and since your `{useSSL:'starttls'}` in fact means `{useSSL:true}`).

You could in principle implement your IMAP client to upgrade the connection to SSL/TLS after using the `STARTTLS` command, but you'd need to be able to upgrade the same socket to SSL/TLS. I can't see anything in the `TCPSocket` documentation that would allow this (in the same way as [`SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(Socket, ...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html#createSocket%28java.net.Socket,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20boolean%29) does in Java, for example).

*EDIT:*

After a quick look at the [TCPSocket.js](http://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/network/src/TCPSocket.js) source code, it seems that it does support `starttls` indeed, but this only makes sense with the undocumented `upgradeToSecure` method.

You might be able to implement IMAP+STARTTLS this way: initiate a plain IMAP connection, and then upgrade to SSL/TLS with the `STARTTLS` command, as described in [RFC 2595](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2595). This is normally done on port 143, but since your server is (rather incorrectly) configured for this on port 993, it should work there too.

Comment: Hi Bruno. useSSL : 'starttls' is acceptable according to source code, it automatically converts it to true/false (I checked it). I also didn't find any way in API to upgrade socket. But thanks for points 2 and 3, I'll try to check it.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a certificate error, that's an SSL protocol error.  SSL packages data into 'frames' or 'records'. (pretty much packets, but at the SSL level rather than the socket level).  There is a maximum length for these frames (16kb, I believe), and the server sent a frame longer than that.  I couldn't tell you why: but maybe their certificate is too big and their SSL lib has bugs.